# Preparing test data for sentiment analysis in Tensor Flow

Tags: natural-language, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis

1) I want to do Sentiment Analysis using RNN + Tensor Flow + (Keras)

2) Is it necessary to prepare test data for sentiment analysis, using RNN, (or any Neural Network), in a certain format ? If so is there any reference to the structure ?

Comment: If there are multiple questions, may be it is better to break into different questions.

Comment: Done. I think i had 2 parts , and you answered one part. I removed the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, neural network usually only takes numerical input. You need some encoding schemes to make a sentence into a numerical vector. Here is one link the will teach you step by step how to do it.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-deep-learning-keras/

Keras also has example code for it

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py

Comment: Okay thanks. But i wanted to know why permutations and combinations of the sentence have been created in test data.